# How to prevent React Native FlatList with TextInput inside ListHeaderComponent scroll to the top of the list on focus

Tags: react-native, scroll, header, sticky, flatlist

I have a textinput inside listHeaderComponent with stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} which keeps it at top of the list, but for some reason its scrolls to the top of the flatlist onFocus of the textinput, how can i prevent this from happening ?

snack example android
[snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@olegwork330/autoscrolling-on-textinput-focus)

it isn't supposed to scroll to the top of the list onFocus of the input